# Flutter auto_route, Error: Type 'RouteInformationReportingType' not found

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am trying to use auto_route in my flutter project but I have some problems setting it up.
I have followed the set up guide at [auto_route_pub](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) and other guides on youtube but for some reason it will not compile.

My router.dart looks like

```
import 'package:auto_route/annotations.dart';
import 'package:universe_ddd/presentation/authentication/authentication_screen.dart';
import 'package:universe_ddd/presentation/main_flow/main_flow_screen.dart';
import 'package:universe_ddd/presentation/splash/splash_screen.dart';

@MaterialAutoRouter(replaceInRouteName: 'Page,Route', routes: [
  AutoRoute(
    initial: true,
    path: '/',
    page: SplashScreen,
    children: [RedirectRoute(path: '*', redirectTo: '')],
  ),
  AutoRoute(
    path: '/authentication',
    page: AuthenticationScreen,
    children: [RedirectRoute(path: '*', redirectTo: '')],
  ),
  AutoRoute(
    path: '/mainFlow',
    page: MainFlowScreen,
    children: [RedirectRoute(path: '*', redirectTo: '')],
  ),
  RedirectRoute(path: '*', redirectTo: '/authentication')
])
class $AppRouter {}
```

The generated file:

```
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart' as _i4;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' as _i5;

import '../authentication/authentication_screen.dart' as _i2;
import '../main_flow/main_flow_screen.dart' as _i3;
import '../splash/splash_screen.dart' as _i1;

class AppRouter extends _i4.RootStackRouter {
  AppRouter([_i5.GlobalKey<_i5.NavigatorState>? navigatorKey])
      : super(navigatorKey);

  @override
  final Map<String, _i4.PageFactory> pagesMap = {
    SplashScreen.name: (routeData) {
      return _i4.MaterialPageX<dynamic>(
          routeData: routeData, child: const _i1.SplashScreen());
    },
    AuthenticationScreen.name: (routeData) {
      return _i4.MaterialPageX<dynamic>(
          routeData: routeData, child: const _i2.AuthenticationScreen());
    },
    MainFlowScreen.name: (routeData) {
      return _i4.MaterialPageX<dynamic>(
          routeData: routeData, child: const _i3.MainFlowScreen());
    }
  };

  @override
  List<_i4.RouteConfig> get routes => [
        _i4.RouteConfig(SplashScreen.name, path: '/', children: [
          _i4.RouteConfig('*#redirect',
              path: '*',
              parent: SplashScreen.name,
              redirectTo: '',
              fullMatch: true)
        ]),
        _i4.RouteConfig(AuthenticationScreen.name,
            path: '/authentication',
            children: [
              _i4.RouteConfig('*#redirect',
                  path: '*',
                  parent: AuthenticationScreen.name,
                  redirectTo: '',
                  fullMatch: true)
            ]),
        _i4.RouteConfig(MainFlowScreen.name, path: '/mainFlow', children: [
          _i4.RouteConfig('*#redirect',
              path: '*',
              parent: MainFlowScreen.name,
              redirectTo: '',
              fullMatch: true)
        ]),
        _i4.RouteConfig('*#redirect',
            path: '*', redirectTo: '/authentication', fullMatch: true)
      ];
}

/// generated route for
/// [_i1.SplashScreen]
class SplashScreen extends _i4.PageRouteInfo<void> {
  const SplashScreen({List<_i4.PageRouteInfo>? children})
      : super(SplashScreen.name, path: '/', initialChildren: children);

  static const String name = 'SplashScreen';
}

/// generated route for
/// [_i2.AuthenticationScreen]
class AuthenticationScreen extends _i4.PageRouteInfo<void> {
  const AuthenticationScreen({List<_i4.PageRouteInfo>? children})
      : super(AuthenticationScreen.name,
            path: '/authentication', initialChildren: children);

  static const String name = 'AuthenticationScreen';
}

/// generated route for
/// [_i3.MainFlowScreen]
class MainFlowScreen extends _i4.PageRouteInfo<void> {
  const MainFlowScreen({List<_i4.PageRouteInfo>? children})
      : super(MainFlowScreen.name,
            path: '/mainFlow', initialChildren: children);

  static const String name = 'MainFlowScreen';
}
```

The AppRouter is initiated in the AppWidget that looks like:

```
import 'package:universe_ddd/presentation/routes/router.gr.dart';

import '../../application/auth/auth_bloc.dart';
import '../../injection.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class AppWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  AppWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final _appRouter = AppRouter();

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => getIt<AuthBloc>()
            ..add(
              const AuthEvent.authCheckRequested(),
            ),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp.router(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'UniVerse',
        routeInformationParser: _appRouter.defaultRouteParser(),
        routerDelegate: _appRouter.delegate(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I try to compile the app it gives the following error:

```
../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/auto_route-3.2.0/lib/src/router/provider/auto_route_information_provider.dart:30:17: 
Error: Type 'RouteInformationReportingType' not found.
      {required RouteInformationReportingType type}) {
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/auto_route-3.2.0/lib/src/router/provider/auto_route_information_provider.dart:29:8: 
Error: The method 'AutoRouteInformationProvider.routerReportsNewRouteInformation' doesn't have the named parameter 'isNavigation' of overridden method 'RouteInformationProvider.routerReportsNewRouteInformation'.
  void routerReportsNewRouteInformation(RouteInformation routeInformation,
       ^
../../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/router.dart:1340:8: 
Context: This is the overridden method ('routerReportsNewRouteInformation').
  void routerReportsNewRouteInformation(RouteInformation routeInformation, {bool isNavigation = true}) {}
       ^
../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/auto_route-3.2.0/lib/src/router/controller/auto_router_delegate.dart:30:17: 
Error: Getter not found: 'RouteInformationReportingType'.
          type: RouteInformationReportingType.navigate,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/auto_route-3.2.0/lib/src/router/controller/auto_router_delegate.dart:30:11:
 Error: No named parameter with the name 'type'.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
```

The rest of my dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

  freezed_annotation: ^1.1.0
  dartz: ^0.10.1
  firebase_core: ^1.10.6
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.4
  flutter_bloc: ^8.0.0
  injectable: ^1.5.0
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.5
  auto_route: ^3.2.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  injectable_generator: ^1.5.2
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  build_runner: ^2.1.7
  mockito: ^5.0.17
  freezed: ^1.1.0
  auto_route_generator: ^3.2.0
```

I am using flutter 2.5.3, dart 2.14.4, auto_route: ^3.2.0, auto_route_generator: ^3.2.0.
I cant find any problem like this on an earlier page so I am probably doing something stupid, but can´t figure it out =) If anyone have an idea of what is wrong or have seen a similar problem i would be greatful for any advice.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

[image]
you can try to update your flutter according to changelog of auto route.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31277607)